# AWS-SDK-NET MediaConvert - When using container type MP4 fails with validation message

Tags: .net-core, aws-sdk-net, aws-media-convert

I am getting this error when creating a MediaConvert job

*/outputGroups/0/outputs/0/containerSettings: Should have at most 2 properties*

This is my ContainerSettings:

```
ContainerSettings mp4ContainerSettings = new ContainerSettings()
            {
                Container = ContainerType.MP4,
                Mp4Settings = new Mp4Settings()
                {
                    CslgAtom = Mp4CslgAtom.INCLUDE,
                    FreeSpaceBox = Mp4FreeSpaceBox.EXCLUDE,
                    MoovPlacement = Mp4MoovPlacement.PROGRESSIVE_DOWNLOAD
                }                
            };
```

Any ideas?

I also tested and got same results with

```
 ContainerSettings thumbnailsContainerSettings = new ContainerSettings()
            {
                Container = ContainerType.RAW
            };
```

I tested with container type M3U8 and it executed successfully.

Comment: are you able to find the reason for this?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add my comments on this. I don't remember how I solved it. I refactored it a little bit but at the end of the day the settings are the same

Answer (score 0):

The generated container settings declaration for a MP4 output should resemble:

"ContainerSettings": {
"Container": "MP4",
"Mp4Settings": {
"CslgAtom": "INCLUDE",
"FreeSpaceBox": "EXCLUDE",
"MoovPlacement": "PROGRESSIVE_DOWNLOAD"
}
}

You can see the all the supported options for each output type using the cli flag:  % aws mediaconvert --endpoint $EP create-job --generate-cli-skeleton

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, if I load a json file with same configuration in python it works. But if I construct the container settings in net core it fails with a wrong validation.